# How to configure Karma

Tags: angular, karma-runner

Here is my root directory
  `src/tsfolders/.ts files
 public/src/jsfolders/.js files`.

And Karma config

```
module.exports = function(config) {
```

config.set({
    basePath: '.',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-htmlfile-reporter')
    ],

```
customLaunchers: {
  // From the CLI. Not used here but interesting
  // chrome setup for travis CI using chromium
  Chrome_travis_ci: {
    base: 'Chrome',
    flags: ['--no-sandbox']
  }
},
files: [
  // System.js for module loading
  'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
  'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',

  // Polyfills
  'node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.js',

  // Reflect and Zone.js
  'node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js',
  'node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js',
  'node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js',
  'node_modules/zone.js/dist/async-test.js',
  'node_modules/zone.js/dist/fake-async-test.js',

  // RxJs.
  { pattern: 'node_modules/rxjs/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false },
  { pattern: 'node_modules/rxjs/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false },

  // Angular 2 itself and the testing library
  {pattern: 'node_modules/@angular/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false},
  {pattern: 'node_modules/@angular/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false},

  'karma-test-shim.js',

   {pattern: 'public/src/**/*.js', included: false, watched: true},

          // paths to support debugging with source maps in dev tools
    {pattern: 'src/**/*.ts', included: false, watched: false},
    {pattern: 'src/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false}
],

// proxied base paths for loading assets
proxies: {
  // required for component assets fetched by Angular's compiler
  '/src/': '/base/src/'

},

exclude: [],
preprocessors: {},
reporters: ['progress', 'html'],

// HtmlReporter configuration
htmlReporter: {
  // Open this file to see results in browser
  outputFile: '_test-output/tests.html',

  // Optional
  pageTitle: 'Unit Tests',
  subPageTitle: __dirname
},

port: 9876,
colors: true,
logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
autoWatch: true,
browsers: ['Chrome'],
singleRun: false
```

})
}

Can someone explain how to configure Karma paths, cause now it doesn't see any of my tests and return error "Executed 0 of 0 ERROR"

Comment: is your test cases available in src folder itself or outside it? Secondly please check your 'test.ts' file as well for the path included to see the test files.

Answer (score 0):

Karma will look for your files relative you where your Karma.conf.js file is.

So if your Karma.conf.js file is at C:\YourName\MyApp\Karma.conf.js

Then putting

```
 { pattern: 'node_modules/rxjs/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false }
```

will get Karma to look at

```
C:/YourName/MyApp/node_modules/rxjs/        and beyond
```